# Why favor the use of %w over ['foo', 'bar']

Tags: ruby, coding-style, rubocop

I ran my code through rubocop. It has a rule:  [`%w` or `%W` for an array of words.](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/WordArray)

```
%w(some words here)   
['some', 'words', 'here']
```

Why should `%w` be favored over `['some', 'words', 'here']`? Both seem to be equal. Is it just less typing, or are we trying to be cryptic for the sake of being confusing?

Comment: As DaveNewton has noted in the answer, your `%w` notation is wrong, to begin with.

Comment: The less syntax junk there is in your code, the easier it is to read. `%w` looks quite clean at a glance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For three reasons:

1. %w is more idiomatic ruby

When reading ruby code you will come across %w a lot when dealing with     an array of strings. While you can write a simple [] and achieve the same thing %w is the 'ruby way'.

2. %w conveys more meaning than []

The second and I think more important reason is %w conveys a more specific meaning. An array created with %w can only hold strings, it cannot for example hold integers. So the code is showing its intent clearer to the programmer by pointing out that this array will only ever have strings.

3. The Ruby philosophy: Multiple ways to do one thing.

Ruby has a philosophy (rightly or wrongly) that the language should give the programmer multiple options to do the same thing so they can do what they think is right. So if you disagree with the rule thats ok :) Here is an snippet from an interview with the creator of Ruby [Yukihiro Matsumoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto)

> Ruby inherited the Perl philosophy of having more than one way to do the same thing. I inherited that philosophy from Larry Wall, who is my hero actually. I want to make Ruby users free. I want to give them the freedom to choose. People are different. People choose different criteria. But if there is a better way among many alternatives, I want to encourage that way by making it comfortable. So that's what I've tried to do. Maybe Python code is a bit more readable. Everyone can write the same style of Python code, so it can be easier to read, maybe. But the difference from one person to the next is so big, providing only one way is little help even if you're using Python, I think. I'd rather provide many ways if it's possible, but encourage or guide users to choose a better way if it's possible. - Yukihiro Matsumoto 2003 http://www.artima.com/intv/rubyP.html

Comment: It's also nice that `w` means *words* or *whitespace-separated*. In modern Ruby you also get `%i` which is the same for *interns*, otherwise known as symbols, but that's less easy to remember.

Comment: Isn't your first point a circular logic? It is the conventional way because it is forced to be so?

Comment: I don't see how your third point answers or is relevant to the question. It rather seems to indicate something in the opposite direction. Isn't setting a convention to limit the use of various notations going against "there is more than one way to do it"-philosophy?

Comment: @sawa - I don't think it is, most (maybe all) languages have there own idiomatic style. In C# a List type is often preferred to an array for example. It certainly isn't forced however - thats why I added the third point to highlight the multiple options for doing something are to give a programmer more freedom :)

Comment: @Tom There's a technical reason why collections are often preferred over arrays, though. In this case the reason isn't technical.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Yes thats true - it was more the first example I thought of! But in my mind at least using [ ] or %w() isn't a huge deal. If the developer is not too bothered by the syntax then use %w() for the first two reasons. If it does bother them then just use an [ ] (following reason 3) and move on!

Answer (score 6):

It's only "cryptic" if you're not familiar with the shortcut.

I've never been convinced it's worth *enforcing*, but you can turn off this particular warning and not worry about it if that's how you roll.

The syntax is actually cleaner yet:

```
%w(some words here)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is (partially because) less typing. But not only that. Less typing typically means less reading; it is easier to read. It is not trying to be cryptic, it is the opposite. Furthermore, as the array gets longer, the advantage and temptation of using `%w` becomes larger, and it would rather be cryptic to use different notations depending on the length of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually:

`%w(some words here)`

without commas. And you could use any matching “(”, “[”, “{”, “<” to enclose them.

It goes in the same line of having parentheses as optional for method definitions. Better readability. And not cryptic as long as you know what it is for.

Refer to [Ruby Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) for more info.

Comment: I don't get the "It goes in the same line of having parentheses as optional for method definitions" part. In method definition, parentheses is optional. In `%w` notation, you need some delimiter.

Comment: While defining a method, ex: `first_name`, you could write it as def first_name() end or def first_name end, making parentheses as optional for readability, especially if there are arguments for that method. Thats what I meant.

Comment: Did you read the latter part of my comment? How does that make parentheses (or any other delimiter) optional for `%w`?

Comment: I didn't mean parentheses as optional in the context of `%w`. I meant in the context of readability, the same way as parentheses are optional, in the same readability, you could use `%w(a b c)` for defining arrays rather than ['a', 'b', 'c']. Hope it makes sense.